# There is no package called 'foreign'

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, hmisc

I'm trying to install the package 'Hmisc' in R but I'm running into an error, shown below:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'Hmisc' in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called 'foreign'
Traceback:

1. library(Hmisc)
2. tryCatch({
 .     attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc
 .     ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
 .     env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps, exclude, include.only)
 . }, error = function(e) {
 .     P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e))) 
 .         paste(" in", deparse(cc)[1L])
 .     else ""
 .     msg <- gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s%s:\n %s", 
 .         sQuote(package), P, conditionMessage(e))
 .     if (logical.return) 
 .         message(paste("Error:", msg), domain = NA)
 .     else stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
 . })
3. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
4. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
5. value[[3L]](cond)
6. stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
```

I've looked around and can't seem to find any answers.

Comment: The `foreign` package is part of a set that is "quasi" official and "R-recommended" but _not_ required.  This would appear to a local issue the admin of your machine (you? someone else?) needs to correct.

Comment: That would be me. How should I go about correcting it? I'm just starting off with R so any help is appreciated.

Comment: "Normally" when you install a package it autoMAGICally installs all its dependencies. So you are doing some unusual.  Your question is _very_ short on detail (what OS? what version? what archictecture? what command did you run?) so I cannot say more but if you were to google "how to install R package on X" where X is your OS/machine/whatever I am sure you will numerous compelling tutorials and posts.  There is also an entire manual devoted to 'installation and administration' of R itself, and lastly the `install.packages()` function that is the workhorse for all this has documentation too.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of information, I'm running Windows 10 and R version 3.6.1 in Jupyter Notebook. The command I'm running is ```install.packages('Hmisc',repos='https://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/')
   library(Hmisc)```

Comment: I've just figured it out, thank you for your help!